# How to override Maven properties using command like options?

Tags: maven, properties, overriding

I would like to have a `Maven` property that is set to a default unless `-Dmy.prop` is set.

So I went into my parent pom and added the property:

```
<properties>
        <my.prop>ABC</my.prop>
</properties>
```

I ran `mvn clean install -Dmy.prop=XYZ`, hoping the XYZ would override the ABC but it did not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a profile to achieve that behaviour.

```
<profile>
    <id>default-prop-a</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>!prop.a</name>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <prop.a>VALUE</prop.a>
    </properties>
</profile>
```